# Several rdlc files at the same time in the same reportviewer

Tags: rdlc

As per the title, I haven't found any way to generate a report with differente rdlc files at the same time in VB .NET

The point is that I have to create like 8 different reports with different tables and formats, but I need to show them all at once in the reportviewer, so the user can scroll down and see one by one, and of course, print them out in one shot.

I've read something about "PDFtk" to print different reports in different pdfs and merge them down but it's not what I am looking for, because the pdf creation may fail and....and I am pretty sure there must be something like this done already by someone..

Anyone has any idea how to merge them???
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced the same problem, after doing some searching I arrived that the simplest way to achieve what you're looking for is to create a main report and than include your 8 reports as subreport of the main report.

It works great for me. There could be just one problem. If your 8 reports have header and footer it won't be displayed because ssrs just shows the header and footer of the main report and suppresses those of the subreports

Hope this can help you

Comment: I've been reading about it too, but it looks kind of messy because I have to use delegates and stuff to call an event handler to load the subreport....

Comment: I followed this article to load the datasets for my subreports. I know the solution isn't that clean, but it was the only wy I found after a lot of searching. Telerik Reporting has a very nice feature called report book that merges a set of reports to the viewer, I wish SSRS would have the same feature

Comment: Thanks anyway Raphael, I am going to try. I was also thinking then if every report has 25 parameters (loaded 1 by 1 from my own query) the main report would have 8 * 25 = 200 parameters which is kind of exagerated, but yeah, I don´t see any other way and I can´t believe Microsoft didn´t get anything in this matter at all....

Comment: Ok, my problem now is that for some reason I cannot show 2 subreports in the same report parent because the 2nd one gets error.

I've created all the parameters necessary to overpass from the report to the report parent and separately they work fine, but when I put them together, it crashes, WHY????? what am I missing here???

Comment: I, usually when I get that error it was because of a wrong parameter or dataset name i passed to the subreport. I currently load several subreports with no problem, I had your same problem with a report, the only things I could do to solve the problem was to simplify it, so that I could find where I got the exception, rdlc unfortunately doesn't help you al lot with the debugging.

Comment: The point is that I tried both reports separately and they work just fine, they just crash when I put them together..I am getting crazy here....

Comment: I think somehow I've got it working. Seriously, I don't know what I did different from yesterday but it seems to work now.... :D

Answer (score 0):

Just in case is useful for someone else I did it this way:

1./ Create parameter from code like this

`*Dim params as New List(Of ReportParameter)
 params.add(New ReportPArameter("NAME_IN_REPORT", "ANYVALUE") 'Repeat this per each parameter
 With RViewer
    .LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource="ProjectName.ReportName.rdlc"
    .LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
    .RefreshReport()
 End With*`

2./ At the same time you create a main report and create the parameters with the same name you create them in the 1st step (e.g. NAME_IN_REPORT)

3./ Create another report with the structure (tables, lines, textboxes,etc) and create the params as well (because we are gonna have to connect this params with the ones in step 2)

4./ This param association is made in the main report, once we added the subreport, right button over the subreport, subreport properties and Parameters section.

**Name              Value**
NAME_IN_REPORT      [@NAME_IN_REPORT]

At the end, the params travel like this between reports:

code params --> main report params --> subreport params

Hope it helps to someone, otherwise let me know and I'll help you as much as I can